# Calling function in Controller from jquery not working or showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

hi i was trying to call the function in my control using my jquery (ajax) in my cshtml...

my code in my RegisterNewAcct.cshtml which located in Home folder

```
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <a href="#CancelDialogPage" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="dialog" id="opencanceldialog">Cancel</a>
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
</div>
<h2>New Account</h2>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Registration Failed! Check your Registration Details.")
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.NewAcctName)</div>
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.NewAcctName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.NewAcctName)
                </div>

                <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.NewDispName)</div>
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.NewDispName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.NewDispName)
                </div>

                <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.NewEmail)</div>
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.NewEmail)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.NewEmail)
                </div>

                <div>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.NewPassword)</div>
                <div>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.NewPassword)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.NewPassword)
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="validatenewacct"  value="Save" data-theme="b" /> <!-- THIS IS THE SUBMIT BUTTON AND WILL CALL MY JQUERY -->
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**EDIT**

My Javascript below my cshtml

```
    @section Scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#validatenewacct").click(function(e) {
           $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     data: $('form').serialize(),
                     url: "/Home/ValidateNewAccount",
                     contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",         
                     success: function (result) {
                     alert("ok: "+ result);
                     },
                     error: function (result) {
                         alert('Oh no: '+ result);
                     }
                 });
            });
        });
    });

</script>}
```

Code behind the HomeController.cs

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidateNewAccount(Models.HomeModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json("True");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("false");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

**Firebug Error**

Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid JSON primitive: NewAcctName.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: NewAcctName.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your actionresult? Or your ajax call doesn't reach the controller at all?

Comment: Could you also show us your Model constructor?

Comment: Are you sure your form uses the Models.HomeModel user class as strongly typed model ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add controller to the controller name.

Instead of

```
url: "/HomeController/ValidateNewAccount"
```

Should be

```
url: "/Home/ValidateNewAccount"
```

---

In your jQuery you showed `ValidateNewAccount` but the controller you showed in code-behind is `RegisterNewAccount`

Comment: hi sorry for my ignorance.. thanks for you quick reply... now it will display the message.. but the problem is my webpage totally gone. as in blank white page... is it due to the return View(user)?

Comment: Probably because of JSON result. Looking at the controller code, it will never reach the `return View()` line because one of the condition above will be executed and will return true or false. Partial View does not use master pages, so it will be blank with only the content in it. I believe so is JSONResult, because it's like a string and no layout is attached it. So you only get the JSON string and not a full page. Hope that helps?

Comment: Error in your JavaScript or controller could also result in blank page if not handled

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have not write a document.ready function.
try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#validatenewacct").click(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "/Home/ValidateNewAccount",
                     contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",         
                     success: function (result) {
                     alert("ok: "+ result);
                     },
                     error: function (result) {
                         alert('Oh no: '+ result);
                     }
                 });
        });

});
```

**Edited:**

and one more thing your Action ValidateNewAccount wants a parameter and you are not giving them any parameter in $.ajax. try this also:
 $(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#validatenewacct").click(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     data: $('form').serialize(),
                     url: "/Home/ValidateNewAccount",
                     contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",         
                     success: function (result) {
                     alert("ok: "+ result);
                     },
                     error: function (result) {
                         alert('Oh no: '+ result);
                     }
                 });
        });

});
```

Comment: i already put #(document).ready(funtcion(){} but still the problem is the website goes white blank... how can i make may website validate thru ajax using jquery before it will submit....

Comment: sorry for that... topographical error only.. i tried this function already $(document).ready(function() {}

Comment: have you tries this in $.ajax: `data: $('form').serialize(),` see my updated code.

Comment: yes i tried already but there's no luck it will go to blank page

Comment: Please check firebug console window after clicking in button and paste error of firebug here...